# How can i create custom cluster in Maplibre for Angular15

Tags: angular, maplibre-gl

I want to create a map component with maplibre in Angular 15.
I found most of the options using geojson. https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/examples/cluster/

How can I custom implement clustering with JSON data?